# How to get URL from PlacePhotoMetadata

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api

I can't seem to get the url, from the `PlacePhotoMetadata` object. Debugger shows that there is an URL there but I can't seem to access it.
How do you access the URL in the object?

```
val placeId = "ChIJa147K9HX3IAR-lwiGIQv9i4"
val photoMetadataResponse = mGeoDataClient.getPlacePhotos(placeId)
photoMetadataResponse.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
    // Get the list of photos
    val photos = task.result
    // Get the PlacePhotoMetadataBuffer (metadata for all of the photos)
    val photoMetadataBuffer = photos.photoMetadata
    // Get the first photo in the list
    for (photo in photoMetadataBuffer) {
        // Get the attribution text
        val attribution = photo.attributions
    }
}
```

[image: Access to zzhd]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Take a look at the documentation for [`PlacePhotoMetadata`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlacePhotoMetadata). There are methods to download a bitmap of the image, but no methods that return the URL.

To get the photo you should do something like this:

```
// this is your for-loop:
photoMetadataBuffer.forEach { photo ->
    photo.getPhoto(client).setResultCallback({ result ->

        // do whatever you want here:
        showPhotoWithAttribution(photo.attributions, result.getBitmap())

    })
}
```

Note that replacing a `for`-loop with a `forEach` call has no real advantage, it just makes your code look cleaner.

Comment: That's unfortinate :(, well I'll have to do it another way ^^, thanks for the answer